# How to take next index of value in Panda

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to tidy. In the original data, three rows are for a same products but only the first row has the name. These three rows represent 3 different years of sale, and the year is acutual year+1, so if it says "2021.0", it is year 2020

```
  Name     Year     SALE    
0 Apple   2021.0     100
1         2022.0      80
2         2023.0     140
3 Pear    2021.0     50
4         2022.0      40
5         2023.0      30
```

What I want to achieve is to put all three rows of information into the same row, like below

```
 Name    2020 Annual Sale    2021 Annual Sale      2022 Annual Sale
0 Apple       100               80                     140
1 Pear        50                40                     30
```

Can you guys please help with this?
The most difficult part for me is to take the value from the next index.

---------- dataframe ----------

```
data = {
    'Name': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear'],
    'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023],
    'SALE': [100, 80, 140, 50, 40, 30],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) is your best friend

```
data = {
    'Name': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear'],
    'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023],
    'SALE': [100, 80, 140, 50, 40, 30],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Year', values='SALE')
df.columns = [f'{col} Annual Sale' for col in df.columns]
df.index = [name.replace(' ', '') for name in df.index]
```

Output :

```
       2021 Annual Sale  2022 Annual Sale  2023 Annual Sale
Apple               100                80               140
Pear                 50                40                30
```

---------- Replacing Nan with corresponding value in the same row ----------

Given your data looks like this :

```
    'Name': ['Apple', 'Nan', 'Nan', 'Pear', 'Nan', 'Nan'],
    'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023, 2021, 2022, 2023],
    'SALE': [100, 80, 140, 50, 40, 30],
}
```

We can use the [.replace](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace) method with [method="ffill"](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/ref_df_ffill.asp)
which replaces NULL values with values from the previous row.

Simply `df = df.replace('Nan', method='ffill')`

Output :

```
   Name  Year  SALE
0  Apple  2021   100
1  Apple  2022    80
2  Apple  2023   140
3   Pear  2021    50
4   Pear  2022    40
5   Pear  2023    30
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I tried your codes, they worked! I still have one question about fill the empty 'Name'. I have the name in the first row is 'Apple', and NaN in the second and third row. How can I fill the second and third row with the Name in the first row? And the whole data is like that, the fourth row is 'Pear', the fifth and sixth row is NaN.